# Genism Module attribute error for wrappers

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I am going to find the optimal number of topics for LDA. To do this, I used GENSIM as follows :

```
def compute_coherence_values(dictionary, corpus, texts, limit, start=2, step=3):
    coherence_values = []
    model_list = []
    for num_topics in range(start, limit, step):
        model = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word=id2word)
        model_list.append(model)
        coherencemodel = CoherenceModel(model=model, texts=texts, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v')
        coherence_values.append(coherencemodel.get_coherence())

    return model_list, coherence_values
```

But I have an attribute error: I used spyder.

```
AttributeError: module 'gensim.models' has no attribute 'wrappers'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The latest major Gensim release, 4.0, removed the `wrappers` of other library algorithms. Per the ["Migrating from Gensim 3.x to 4" wiki page](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#15-removed-third-party-wrappers):

> **15. Removed third party wrappers**
>
> These wrappers of 3rd party libraries required too much effort. There were no volunteers to maintain and
> support them properly in Gensim.
>
> If your work depends on any of the modules below, feel free to copy it
> out of Gensim 3.8.3 (the last release where they appear), and extend &
> maintain the wrapper yourself.
>
> The removed submodules are:
>
> ```
> - gensim.models.wrappers.dtmmodel
> - gensim.models.wrappers.ldamallet
> - gensim.models.wrappers.ldavowpalwabbit
> - gensim.models.wrappers.varembed
> - gensim.models.wrappers.wordrank
> - gensim.sklearn_api.atmodel
> - gensim.sklearn_api.d2vmodel
> - gensim.sklearn_api.ftmodel
> - gensim.sklearn_api.hdp
> - gensim.sklearn_api.ldamodel
> - gensim.sklearn_api.ldaseqmodel
> - gensim.sklearn_api.lsimodel
> - gensim.sklearn_api.phrases
> - gensim.sklearn_api.rpmodel
> - gensim.sklearn_api.text2bow
> - gensim.sklearn_api.tfidf
> - gensim.sklearn_api.w2vmodel
> - gensim.viz
> ```

If you desperately needed the old support, you could also consider installing & using the older Gensim. (For example, via `pip`, `pip install gensim==3.8.3`.) But in general, the latest version will be best-supported.